# Generating sinwave from array of real

Tags: vhdl

I want to generate sinewave from array of real.

Here is array with 12 samples of sine

```
type memory_type is array (0 to 11) of real;
signal sine : memory_type :=0.50,0.7,0.95,0.99,0.88,0.64,0.36,0.12,0.01,0.05,0.23,0.50);
```

and **i** signal for iterations:

```
signal i : integer range 0 to 10 :=0;
```

Here is the process which generates 2kHz wave based on samples

```
process(clk_2kHz)
begin
if (rst = '1') then
        i <= 0;
    elsif(rising_edge(clk_2kHz)) then
        dataout <= sine(i);
            i <= i + 1;
                if (i = 11) then
                        i<= 0;
                end if;
end if;     
end process;
```

I want to pass this signal to LTC2624 on spartan-3E and get analog sine on output.

Problem is that i am gettin this error:

```
Line 94: Indexed name is not a integer
```

Why is this happening? I know that array contains real values but index number is integer(i think). I tried change i to real but it did not help.
Any sugestions?

Comment: The only place we see in your snippet with an indexed name  is `sine(unsigned(i));` where the `i` is an integer and is not closely related to the array type `unsigned` and ineligible for a type conversion that you don't need anyway. The index type of `memory_type` is integer, the range is constrained and these match the declaration for  `i`. Also note your test should be `if i = 10 then i <= 0; else i <= i + 1; end if;` including the increment. Your present test will get a bounds check error when simulating. Signal updates don't occur during process execution. Reals don't synthesize.

Comment: unsigned(i) was posted here by mistake. I was checking if this would help but it not and i forgot to remove it before asking this question. Sorry about that. So if real don't sythesize - How should i represent sample data?

Comment: An [LTC2624](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ltc2624.html) has a 12 bit representation. Convert  your samples to a binary representation with that accuracy.